# Android App Architecture and Dependency injection

Tags: java, android

I am still confused about Dependency Injection. Before Understanding how the tools like Dagger 2 can help i would like to understand the concept and raw code first.

I have Activity->ViewModel-> Repository-> Retrofit
                                       -> Room DB
this is my current structure.

From what i have understood i can make the repository, Retrofit and Room DB Singleton as i only want to use them Synchronously.

My Idea was to have one Instance of the repository which would be able to be connected to multiple view models and activities. This would allow me to simply change the Viewmodels and activities and carry out different tasks.

Now what i am confused about is :-

1) When i Make a repository

```
public GeofenceRepository(MtsAPI mtsAPI, UserLoginDetailsDao dao, Application 
context) {

    if (rSoleInstance != null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Use getInstance() method to get the 
single instance of this class.");
    }
    else {

        this.mtsAPI = mtsAPI;
        this.dao = dao;
        this.context = context;
        MtsApiInterface mtsApiInterface = 
        RetrofitInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(MtsApiInterface.class);
        AppDatabase db = AppDatabase.getInMemoryDatabase(context);
        dao = db.userLoginDetailsDao();
    }

}

public static GeofenceRepository getInstance(MtsAPI 
 mtsAPI,UserLoginDetailsDao dao,Application context) {
    //Double check locking pattern
    if (rSoleInstance == null) { //Check for the first time

        synchronized (GeofenceRepository.class) {   //Check for the second 
        time.
            //if there is no instance available... create new one
            if (rSoleInstance == null) {
                rSoleInstance = new GeofenceRepository(mtsAPI, dao,context);
            }
        }
    }

    return rSoleInstance;
}
```

I have no idea what i am doing to be honest.. How to make sure Repository is a singleinstance which creates a single instance of Retrofit and Room DB.

How do i then use the repository in my view model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to make sure Repository is a singleinstance?

First Make the `GeofenceRepository` constructor **private**, as you are going to need **single** instance anyway and should use it via `getInstance()` method only. So no need to throw `RuntimeException`

```
private GeofenceRepository(MtsAPI mtsAPI, UserLoginDetailsDao dao, Application 
context) {
        this.mtsAPI = mtsAPI;
        this.dao = dao;
        this.context = context;
        MtsApiInterface mtsApiInterface = 
        RetrofitInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(MtsApiInterface.class);
        AppDatabase db = AppDatabase.getInMemoryDatabase(context);
        dao = db.userLoginDetailsDao();
    }
}
```

Keep `getInstance()` method as it is and always access instance of this class using that method only.

Follow the same pattern for **Room DB** and **Retrofit**, accessing using `getInstance()` only. So it will use single instances of those classes too.

> How do i then use the repository in my view model?

Just call the `getInstance()` method on repository by passing **application context** instance in `ViewModel` which extends [AndroidViewModel](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/AndroidViewModel)
So, you can get context in your `ViewModel` and can pass it to your Repository's `getInstance()` method.

> To check if Singleton objects are actually maintained

Use Android Studio Debugger and check every time object reference is having same reference number as shown in image

[image: Android Debugger]

Still I would recommend to do this with **Dagger 2** which will be helpful to inject lot of dependencies at a time. Maintaining multiple dependencies using `getInstance()` method is not practical.

Comment: @nadeem jamal Consider approving this answer if this worked for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Dependency injection means that you can put your dependencies through some way inside the object. It can be through a constructor:

```
new MyClass(someDependency);
```

or through a setter:

```
myClass.setDependency(someDependency);
```

instead of:

```
class MyClass {
  private SomeDependenciesInterface = new SomeDependency();
}
```

Using singletons rises the temptation to just write SomeDependency.getInstance() and get the instance, maybe without even keeping a reference as an instance variable.
I would recommend you to keep the singletons out of your code. Just because something is probably going to exist only once, doesn't mean it has to be a singleton.
Additionally, you will notice what you have to do if it isn't a singleton: Pass it as a dependency to **every** object that it needs.